# Using authentication with Proxy

Tags: realbasic, realstudio

Sorry for the double post: a friend of mine asked this on the mailing list but no one answered.

I would like to know how to correctly use the `ProxyAuthenticationRequired` event of an HTTPSocket. I mean, how can I pass the login/password if the proxy asks for the authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used a proxy with the HTTPSocket class, but I think this is how it works.

The [ProxyAuthenticationRequired](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/HTTPSocket.ProxyAuthenticationRequired) event passes four parameters, the proxy realm as a string, the HTTP headers as an [InternetHeaders](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/InternetHeaders) object, and the username and password as strings. The username and password are passed [**ByRef**](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/ByRef), so I believe the idea is for you to set these parameters yourself and then Return True from the ProxyAuthenticationRequired event:

```vb
Event ProxyAuthenticationRequired(Realm as String, Headers as InternetHeaders, ByRef Name as String, ByRef Password as String ) As Boolean
  Name = "MyUserName"
  Password = "MyPass"
  Return True
End Event
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time to help me out on this ! I've already tried this but without the "Return True", think now it will finally work !